# Getting the position of input field in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular.
I have a base component named name.component.ts/html.
Using this component I created four other components - first-name.component.ts/html, last-name, middle-name and maiden-name.

I place all four components on one screen so you have some thing like:

First name  : _____

Last name   : _____

Middle name : _____

Maiden-name : _____

On right click I want to open a sub menu but I want a different sub menu for each field.
The easiest way is to get the right click event and from the event the name of the input field it was on. But all input field's name is the same as they are all based on name.component.ts/html.
An input filed is a rectangle. I figured that If I can get the 4 points of the rectangle somehow and then get the position of the click using event.clientX & event.clientY I could know on what input the right click was done and act accordingly.
My question is - in name.component how do I get all four coordinates of the rectangle?
This all 4 instances of name.component can listen to right click event comming from app.component and decide if the event was ment for them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you detect right click in each component (first-name.component.ts, last-name.component.ts, ...), you don't have to the position on each item( too long way)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would generally advice you to not mix and match logic and layout. That sounds like a dangerous mixture when it comes to responsiveness.

My first aproach would be something like the following:

name-component.html

```html
<app-first-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.FIRST_NAME)"/>
<app-last-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.LAST_NAME)"/>
<app-middle-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.MIDDLE_NAME)"/>
<app-maiden-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.MAIDEN_NAME)"/>
```

Where DialogType is an enum that tracks the types of ContextDialogs you want to open (to avoid magic strings) and within your `openContextDialog` function your open the corresponding type of dialog.

Note:
This makes use of Angular 15.1 self closing component syntax for earlier versions you would have to change this to

```html
<app-first-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.FIRST_NAME)">
</app-first-name>
<app-last-name (contextMenu)="openContextDialog(DialogType.LAST_NAME)">
</app-last-name>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your question. But as I understood To get the coordinates of each input field within the name.component template, you can use the **ElementRef** and **ViewChild** decorators from **@angular/core**.

※But I don't recommend to do this. Try to Pass a unique identifier to each input field, such as an index or a custom attribute, so that you can identify the field in the directive and determine which sub-menu to display.

In your name.component.ts file, you can define a ViewChild decorator for each input element like this:

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class NameComponent {
  @ViewChild('firstNameInput', { static: false }) firstNameInputRef: ElementRef;
}
```

In the template file name.component.html, you can give each input element a unique identifier using the id attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="firstNameInput" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
```

Then, within a method that handles the right-click event, you can use the **ClientRect** object to determine if the click event occurred within the boundaries of a specific input field:

```
handleRightClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  const firstNameRect = this.firstNameInputRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  const x = event.clientX;
  const y = event.clientY;

  if (this.isWithinRect(firstNameRect, x, y)) {
    // handle right-click on first name input field
  } 
}

isWithinRect(rect: ClientRect, x: number, y: number): boolean {
  return x >= rect.left && x <= rect.right && y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom;
}
```

The **isWithinRect()** method checks whether the given x and y coordinates are within the boundaries of the given **ClientRect** object. If the click event occurred within one of the input fields, you can handle the right-click event accordingly.

Comment: I started with ViewChild but its a problem. I have the name.component to check that the user does not put numbers or special characters in the name. I also have the template so all names will show the same. When you write id="firstNameInput" it is in the name template so should be id="nameInput". I put then name.component into first-name.component etc. Now I put <app-first-name> and <app-last-name> on the screen so I have 4 inputs named "nameInput" on the screen. So I can't use ViewChild. Maybe there is a way to get MY ViewChild inside a component without supplying a name.